# Replace a string in a file with variables located in another file

Tags: shell, awk

I would like to replace a string in a text file with a couple variables that exist in every line in another file, and then save the destination file under a new name. Below is an example and my code:

```
$ cat ref            # contains variables as the name in each line
item1
item2
item3

$ cat main           # main inventory. the string xxx will be replaced with item# and modified file to be saved under the same variable name
sale inventory
this record is for xxx
end of inventory
```

Desired output files [3 files. below is item1]:

```
$ cat item1
sale inventory
this record is for item1
end of inventory
```

My code with `awk`

```
awk -v fname=ref($0) '/xxx/ {$5 = fname}1' main >> "$fname"

Error: syntax error: got (, expecting Newline
```

Thanks for you help in advance

Comment: Can `xxx` contain any regexp metachars (e.g. `.` or `*`)? Can `xxx` appear elsewhere in the input as a substring (e.g. `axxx`)? Can any of the `item`s from `ref` contain `&` or any other backreference chars (e.g. `this&that`)? If the answer to any of those is "yes" then you can't use any `*sub()` solution without adding word boundaries and/or sanitizing characters.

Answer (score 1):

One `awk` approach:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { names[$0]; next }               # 1st file; save entries as indices of the names[] array
        { for (fname in names) {          # 2nd file; loop through names[] indices
              line=$0                     # make copy of current input line
              gsub(/xxx/,fname,line)      # replace "xxx" with contents of "fname" variable
              print line > fname          # print modified line to file
          }
        }
' ref main
```

**NOTES:**

- this will maintain an open file descriptor for each new output file
- for a 'large' number of files this could cause some versions of `awk` to abort with an error stating it ran out of file descriptors
- while this issue can be addressed with additional coding, we would need a better idea on the expected max size of both files (number of lines in `ref`, MBytes in `main`)

This generates:

```
$ head item?
==> item1 <==
sale inventory
this record is for item1
end of inventory

==> item2 <==
sale inventory
this record is for item2
end of inventory

==> item3 <==
sale inventory
this record is for item3
end of inventory
```

Comment: This is my favorite. Only consideration is whether there can be more than one `"xxx"` contained in the records of `main` and what the OP needs to do with it. That's up to him. But this makes for the shortest implementation.

Answer (score 1):

A similar `awk` approach collecting the records in arrays can be used. Below the `ref` items are collected in the `item` array and the records from `main` are collected in the `main` array. The `END` rule is used to make the substitution on the 2<sup>nd</sup> record of `main` redirecting output to a file named after item, e.g.

```bash
awk '
  FNR == NR {                         # if record from 1st file
    item[++n] = $1                    # store in indexed item array
    next                              # skip to next record
  }
  { main[++m] = $0 }                  # for 2nd file, store record in main
  END {                               # after all records processed
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)              # loop over all items
      for(j=1; j<=m; j++) {           # loop over each record in main
        line = main[j]                # save record in line
        if (j == 2)                   # if 2nd record in main
          sub(/xxx/, item[i], line)   # substitue item for xxx, save in line
        print line >> item[i]         # append line to item file 
      }
  }
' ref main
```

(**note:** the `if (j == 2)` line just limits the number of times `sub(...)` is called to the 2<sup>nd</sup> line. If you want to check and substitute `itemX` for every occurrence of `"xxx"`, you can remove the `if(...)` and choose either `gsub(...)` or `sub(...)` depending on whether there can be more than one occurrence of `"xxx"` per-line)

**Example Use/Output**

Pasting the above at the command line in the directory containint the files `ref` and `main` produces:

```
$ l item*
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 57 Apr 15 10:06 item1
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 57 Apr 15 10:06 item2
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 57 Apr 15 10:06 item3
```

With contents:

```
$ cat item1
sale inventory
this record is for item1
end of inventory

$ cat item2
sale inventory
this record is for item2
end of inventory

$ cat item3
sale inventory
this record is for item3
end of inventory
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve it, you can use `awk` in a loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

vars=$(cat ref.txt)
template=main.txt

for var in $vars; do
    awk -v var="$var" '{gsub(/xxx/, var)}1' "$template" > "output_$var"
done
```

Alternative version with `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash
vars=$(cat ref.txt)
template=main.txt

for var in $vars; do
    sed "s/xxx/$var/g" "$template" > "output_$var"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with just `awk` after creating an output directory `out/`
I'm using the included [readfile](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Readfile.html) extension.

```
mkdir out
awk '@load "readfile"; BEGIN {main = readfile("main"); backup = main}; {sub(/xxx/, $0, main); print main > "out/" $0; main = backup}' ref
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for `@load` and `readfile` (and also `> "out/" $0` without parens and not closing the output files will only work in some awks, including GNU).

Answer (score 0):

I would use Ruby for such a project:

```
ruby -e '
template=File.open(ARGV[1]).read
File.open(ARGV[0]).
    each_line.with_index(1){|tgt,i| 
        fn=File.open("#{ARGV[1]}_#{i}","w")
        fn.write(template.sub(/\bxxx\b/, tgt.chomp))
        fn.close
}
' ref main
```

Or Perl:

```
perl -0777 -nE '
    if(!$#ARGV){@arr=split(/\R/, $_); next}
    $s=$_;
    for $e (@arr){ 
        open(FH, ">", "${ARGV}_${\(++$cnt)}") || die;
        s/\bxxx\b/$e/; 
        print FH;
        close(FH);
        $_=$s; 
    }
' ref main
```

Or you could use Bash/sed:

```
# fast to write, great for small files, not so great for huge 'main'
while IFS= read -r tgt; do
    (( ++cnt ))
    sed -E "s/xxx/${tgt}/" main > "main_${cnt}"
done  < ref
```

Any of those results:

```
$ head main_*
==> main_1 <==
sale inventory
this record is for item1
end of inventory

==> main_2 <==
sale inventory
this record is for item2
end of inventory

==> main_3 <==
sale inventory
this record is for item3
end of inventory
```